# Set ntp time to specific timezone

Tags: c++, unix, time, ntp

I'm working on an embedded platform based on *unix*. Is it possible to set the *ntp* time to a specific timezone and get information about the country the device is located at?

Comment: NTP operates in UTC, and most operating systems keep track of time that way. Timezones are only used when converting the time for display to users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [NTP timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Timestamps) represents the number of seconds since 00:00 on January 1, 1900 (70 calendar years before the traditional [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of 1970-01-01).

This base time is GMT / UTC, so it doesn't contain any time zone information.

Unix-like systems conventionally represent times in UTC, and convert that to the local time zone as needed.

Time zone information therefore has to be maintained separately.